# How do I protect an individual cell?

Tags: libreoffice

I want to particular cell protected in libreoffice cal. Whole sheet is protected but single cell is not protected. Please guide me how we can protect a single cell in LibreOffice?

Answer (score 2):

Cell protection is available in **Format -> Cells... -> Cell Protection**. Check that "Protected" has a tick.

You can see in the side note that Cell protection is only effective after the sheet has been protected. To protect sheet, go to **Tools -> Protect Document -> Sheet**.